# Android Custom ProgressBar Shape and Animation

Tags: android, progress-bar, customization, loading, shapes

I'm trying to find some resources about how to create an custom ProgressBar for an application. I have done simple loading animations like horizontal line or indeterminate circle, but now i'm trying to make something more complex, with a different shape.

I found that 500PX application has an custom shape ProgressBar, the infinite sign that is filled by another color. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how I can achieve something like that?

I have read & made something with Drawable Animations, but it seems overkill and it requires a lot of image resources for the progress to be as smooth as possible(or maybe I'm doing something wrong).

Thank you.

Comment: all you need is a Drawable that you assign via setProgressDrawable()

Comment: And how can i create that drawable with a custom shape ? (like 500px did) ... and after that how to set the progress to know how to fill the drawable?

Comment: step #1 extend Drawable class, #2 override getIntrinsic*(), #3 override onLevelChange() #4 override draw()

Comment: And how I can achieve creating a custom shape? For example the infinity sign? I only know of the basic shapes: `drawCircle, drawOval, drawRect, drawRoundRect, drawArc, drawLine`; that are drawn into an rectangular region. If you have a good tutorial or any other resources to recommend it would be great. Thank you again.

Comment: see drawPath, also you can drawBitmap as well, for drawing Paths as a Drawable see https://github.com/pskink/PathDrawable

Comment: Thank you, I will need to do more research regarding this. I still don't get how I achieve this but atleast now I'm heading in the right direction :)

Comment: if you want to use Paths install inkscape app, it saves drawings in svg format, so you can design simple shapes

Comment: I never used svg files before, but from what I've read Android doesn't support SVG out of the box, I will need a special library to parse these files. This would seem too much work just for some custom made shape. And woulnd't I need to create multiple resources to create the loading effect ? The same as with Drawable Animations but without the hashle to create these shapes (I could just create multiple resources for the custom shape in Photoshop).